# Gurobi variable creation giving different name than what I input

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to figure out why my gurobi variable name is different from what I input.

Here is my code:

```
v_dc_mfc_wc = m.addVars(total_wc, name=v_dc_mfc_weightcube, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

where

```
v_dc_mfc_weightcube = ['v1_Pennsylvania_BKN-2']
total_wc = len(v_dc_mfc_weightcube)
```

It is a list because variable sometimes have multiple items in it.

The result I am getting:

```
v_dc_mfc_wc = {0: <gurobi.Var v1_Pennsylvania_BKN-2[0]>}
```

For some reason, even tho the name doesn't have '[0]' in the end, the variable name just keep having it.  My observation is that when the list only has one item, this happens, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: `<gurobi.Var v1_Pennsylvania_BKN-2[0]>` That's not a name; it's a _value_.

Comment: That is some kind of custom class object, and that's how the class prints instances of itself.

Comment: @JohnGordon <gurobi.Var v3_Severn_BKN-2> This is what another variable looks like.

Comment: Custom class objects can define a `__str__` method to control how an instance of the class appears when it is printed.  `<gurobi.Var v3_Severn_BKN-2>` is how that class decided to print itself.  There's nothing magical or unusual here...

Comment: I am not saying it is magical or unusual, just that I need to overcome this to make my model work because having a extra "[0]" in my variable name makes me unable to search for the variable that I want.

Comment: What do you mean "search for the variable"?  Search how exactly?